# Counting clicks using integer++ OnTouchListener

Tags: android, integer, ontouchlistener

I have a method to count clicks and then do something after some number of clicks. It works fine but there is a problem with OnTouchListener.
The problem is as long as user is pressing button, integer is increasing and count number is incorrect. Instead of 1 click I get like 10-15 depends how much time user is pressing button.
How can I make it to add +1 per click?
My Method:

```
private void clickCounter() {
        String valueFromFile = read("countFile");
        int intClickCounter = Integer.valueOf(valueFromFile.toString());
        intClickCounter++;
        valueFromFile = Integer.toString(intClickCounter);
        write("" + valueFromFile, "countFile");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, valueFromFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        if (intClickCounter == 10) {
```

And then onTouchListener:

```
@Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int id = v.getId();
        clickCounter();
        switch(id){
                      case R.id.button1:
etc
```

Comment: Use the listener onClick and not onTouch !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply this following condition

```
clickButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if(motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    clickCounter();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Oh yeah why didn't I think of that. Thanks

Comment: Yeah but I need onTouchListener. Its impossible to do what I want with clicklistener